# Get value after ## using regex

Tags: regex

I want to match the value **after** the *"##"* characters in the string *"symbol(##)"*.  Currently I am using this regex: `(/##([\w\d.]*)/)` which returns a match but with no value - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `*` quantifier to `+`.

`##([\w\d.]+)`

`+ Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]`